# Is it possible to have access to the image specified in CFBundleURLIconFile via URL scheme from a different iOS app?

Tags: ios, icons, url-scheme

is it possible to access the icon specified with CFBundleURLIconFile in the info.plist file from a different application? Does application sandboxing prevent it? If so,what is the purpose of this key(in an iOS app of course)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [CoreFoundationKeys docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html): *"CFBundleURLTypes contains an array of dictionaries, each of which describes the URL schemes (http, ftp, and so on) supported by the application. The purpose of this key is similar to that of “CFBundleDocumentTypes,” but it describes URL schemes instead of document types."*

The purpose is to permit applications to register for some type of documents allowing an app to handle the opening of files from other installed app (you surely met the "Open In..." button, for example in Mail when you receive a file).
More on this in the [Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

EDIT:
Sorry, I forgot to answer to your main question: AFAIK the only way to access that key is through UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: Is this really an answer? Does it answer the question how you can access that icon from other apps?